# Make a function behave differently between first and subsequent calls

Tags: python

```
def download():
    upgrade = True
    if upgrade:
        # do a download using tftp
    else:
        # do a download via HTTP
```

As you can see, I have a hard coded value of upgrade that is set to true. In this script, it always does a tftp download.

How do I change the script to do tftp download at the first iteration and in the next iteration when the function download is called, it does a http download?

Comment: first... call in a single instance? Or do you want to actually persist state to storage such that the change spans multiple runs of the program? If it's the latter, you'll need to implement code to read and write from (disk/database/whatever).

Answer (score 6):

For completeness here is the `class` solution:

```
class Download(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.executed = False

    def __call__(self):
        print('http' if self.executed else 'tftp')
        self.executed = True

download = Download()

download()  # tftp
download()  # http
download()  # http
```

This allows you to store state in a non-hackish way across invocations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *closure*, that is, have an inner function which is returned, and this retains an outer state.  This assumes python 3:

```
def init_download():
    upgrade = True

    def inner():
        nonlocal upgrade
        if upgrade:
            print('do a download using tftp')
            upgrade = False
        else:
            print('do a download via HTTP')

    return inner

download = init_download()

download()
download()
download()
```

Gives:

```
do a download using tftp
do a download via HTTP
do a download via HTTP
```

Comment: OP is asking something that can be easily resolved with a default argument and you want to introduce him to closures?

Comment: @ZWiki, eh? The "default argument" is just pushing the work to the outer scope; it doesn't solve the problem, which is of maintaining state across invocations, unless you make it a mutable one -- which is much more of a hack than this is.

Comment: I don't consider this to be a particularly difficult closure as they go, I think its quite a simple introduction to them.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the question then. I suppose a closure is a good way to do so since we don't have C static equivalent

Comment: –1 Gross way to store state, because you can't access the state.  Better to use a callable class if you want that.

Comment: @ZWiki: yes, I always use this when what I really want is a C style `static` (or Perl `state`).   You can't access the state from the outside - that's good (encapsulation), but you can access it from the inner function.

Comment: You could just have an `initialized` variable in your main function/script and use that... then you can tell whether it has been initialized. Wrapping that in a closure seems like overkill.

Comment: @TemporalWolf:  you could, but that means the function is not encapsulated.

Comment: I also think the use of "nonlocal" statement is not the cleanest way to do it, but still thanks for this example because in my use case it was exactly what i needed <3

Answer (score 2):

Restructure your code as below:

```
def download(upgrade=True):

  if upgrade:
     do a download using tftp
  else:
     do a download via HTTP
```

In your second iteration, when you call `download`, use `upgrade=False` as a parameter:

```
download(False)  # download via HTTP
```

Comment: OP said 'iteration,' meaning the function is called multiple times but he doesn't know from the outset which number of call it is.

Comment: This *doesn't actually solve the problem* of changing the `upgrade` switch between the first and subsequent invocations; it just is an instruction to have the caller do that work between the invocations of the function. Is that the right thing to do as a best practice? Yes, absolutely. Does it answer the question? ...ehhhh...

Comment: Rereading the question, I would tend to agree. But I would like OP to confirm, still a bit vague to me.

Comment: This is the only answer that is sort of getting something towards the right approach.  But I would go a bit further, and just write two different functions like `download_tftp` and `download_http`, and keep the logic about which to use outside of the function itself.

Comment: @wim, what about `functools.partial` to split apart the 2 configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can (and should) just take this logic outside of your function, but if you want to pass the same argument each time but still change the behaviour after the first call, you could use the [default mutable argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument):

```
from itertools import count 

def download(c=count()):
    if next(c) == 0:
        print('tftp')
    else:
        print('http')

download()
# tftp
download()
# http
download()
# http
download()
# http
```

The advantage of using `itertools.count` rather than say a list is that you don't accumulate memory with each call.

Comment: –1  just another bad way to store global state

Comment: @Alex thanks and sorry your correction was right, I misread the question, thought they wanted a switch to go back and forth

Comment: @wim can you spell out to me why it's so bad? I agree it's not best practise but how often do you actually find a possible use case for the default mutable argument, could not resist!

Comment: Sure.  It's because when you need stateful execution, the right tool for the job is not a function.

Comment: @wim I agree with you generally but technically all non-trivial closures involve stateful execution.

Comment: I think @wim think this is an X-Y question, and he/she is probably right, but the problem becomes rather trivial if you take the logic outside the function. I'll add a note with that sentiment :)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Right.  And when your problem becomes trivial it's **a good thing**.

Comment: @wim of course! it can be can be instructive to think about these questions still IMO

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly in you only need the literal first call to do thtp, you could make `upgrade` a global variable. Then, when the `download` function is called, you globally set it to False, and it will remain that way for subsequent calls.

Note that this answer is based on a certain reading of OP's question. I am assuming that the script calling this function does not know how many times the function has been called.

```
upgrade = True

def download():
  global upgrade
  if upgrade:
     print('do a download using tftp')
     upgrade = False
  else:
     print('do a download using http')

download() # do a download using tftp
download() # do a download using http
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This does what the OP literally asked for. It's not good practice, but that's on the OP.

Comment: (That said, personally, I'd consider making this a class that implements `__call__()` rather than a function -- that way its state can live internally, as at `self.upgrade`, rather than as a separate global).

Comment: You can (and should) downvote if you think something is not good practice, regardless of what the OP asked about.

Comment: @wim disagreed so long as you point out that it's not good practice. I learn a lot from reading hacky solutions to things and thinking about how they work.

Comment: btw it won't even work, this will be `SyntaxError`, isn't that a good enough reason?  The global statement needs to go before the name is first used.

Comment: True; the `global` declaration should move up to the top of the function body.

Comment: So a code that doesn't work and has a `SyntaxError` gets upvoted 4 times? How?

Comment: It does work without error (corrected the global placement) and most closely addresses what OP was asking, in my opinion.

Comment: @wim If someone makes a simple syntax error, post a comment so they can fix it. It's not worth a downvote.

Comment: @Barmar  Don't tell other users how to use their downvotes.  Btw I would -1 this idea even if it were correctly written in the first place.  I would -2 it if I could.

Comment: @wim Assume "IMHO" at the beginning of my comment.

Answer (score -1):

Since @Alex 's answer is good, but it need a extra step to construct an instance. You will also to store the instance globally.

So I made some change to it. Then you can import it and use it as function.

util.py

```
class Downloader(object):
  _upgrade = False

  @classmethod
  def call(cls):
    if cls._upgrade:
      print('upgrade via http')
    else:
      print('download via tft')
      cls._upgrade = True

def download():
  Downloader.call()
```

main.py (using it)

```
from .util import download

download()
download()
```

This may not thread safe. And if you run it in different processes (e.g. webserver backend), you'd better use a remote storage for the flag (e.g. redis/oss).

Answer (score -2):

You could structure your code in the following:

```
def download(upgrade = False):

    while upgrade == False:
            print("HTTP")
            break
    print("TFTP")

download()
```

This will go through them once and exit the program after. The print statements are just a guide to show you what's happening and when it ends.

Comment: The intent is to only do one operation per call. Maybe you could make a generator out of this, but that would require changing the calling convention.

Comment: Read the above updated code. It does one operation per call then exits.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you call it with `upgrade=False`, then it prints `HTTP` inside the `while` loop, breaks out of the loop, and then prints `TFTP` from the same call.