# How do I count the number of calls of a function in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count the number of calls of the function `f` inside of `inc`. How should I modify the function `main` to do it?

I have this code:

```
def inc(f):
    f()
    f()

def main():
    a = 0
    def f():
        a += 1
    inc(f)
    print(a)  # should print 2

main()
```

But it leads to the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 9, in main
    inc(f)
  File "main.py", line 2, in inc
    f()
  File "main.py", line 8, in f
    a += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: just declare `a` nonlocal (inside `f`).

Comment: @PaulPanzer Please, provide it as a full answer.

Comment: one hacky way would be use the default mutable arg, like `def inc(a=itertools.count()): print(a)`

Comment: relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673304/make-a-function-behave-differently-between-first-and-subsequent-calls

Comment: @Fomalhaut seems someone else has done it for me - which is fine. Btw., depending on what exactly you want you also could remove `a` completely and `cProfile.run('main()')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def inc(f):
    f()
    f()

def main():
    a = 0
    def f():
        nonlocal a
        a += 1
    inc(f)
    print(a)  # should print 2

main()
```

Make **a** nonlocal in f()

Comment: this is overly complicated for no reason. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Please do not advise to use `global` when a `nonlocal` would be enough. Or at least edit your answer to explain that `nonlocal` could be used here.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thankyou.I have made the changes. Can you please state the difference between what I did earlier and now?

Comment: @NegiBabu: it doen't change much in that code. But in a larger script a global is directly accessible to the whole program while a nonlocal is still constraint in the enclosing block. Making something global is generally or good immediate solution that later makes evolutions harder. Best practices recommend to avoid it if you can.

Comment: Using nonlocal or global variables is not a nice solution that may turn around and bite you if your code gets more complicated than this simple example.

Answer (score 8):

The usual way is to create an attribute `func.invocations` for your function `func`, like

```
def func(a):
    func.invocations += 1
    return a + 1

func.invocations = 0
```

and use it like

```
func(1)    # 2
func(10)   # 11
func.invocations  # 2
```

To make the whole thing more reusable and readable you can also create a decorator `counter` that allows you to count the number of calls on any function you like:

```
import functools

def counter(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def helper(*args, **kargs):
        helper.invocations += 1
        return fn(*args, **kargs)
    helper.invocations = 0
    return helper
```

and then use it like

```
@counter
def func(a):
    return a + 1

func(1)    # 2
func(10)   # 11
func.invocations # 2
```

Comment: [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) makes the wrapped function a little more recognizable.

Comment: I have added `functools.wraps` to the code example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple solution, a *global* variable would do the trick.

```
reps = 0

def f():
    global reps 
    reps  += 1
    # do your func stuff here

f()
f()
f()
f()  # called f() 4 times
print(reps)  # -> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this:

```
def inc(f):    
    f()    
    f() 


def main():    
    a = 0     
    def f():     
        f.counter += 1    
    f.counter =0    
    inc(f)     
    print(f.counter) 


main()
```

How functions are objects in python you can create an attribute to count the number of call to that function

Comment: Youre just re-iterating what is already contained in another answer.